# Can't access SelectedItems in XAML Multi-select GridView with MVVM

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to build a UWP app using the MVVM pattern, with the library of choice being MVVMCross. I have a UI project with my views, targeting Universal Windows (build 17763-19041), and a Core project with my business logic and viewmodels, targeting net5.0;netstandard2.0.

I have a GridView with `SelectionMode="Multiple"` and want to access the SelectedItems so I can do something with them. However, the runtime doesn't appear to agree with me, because, for starters, SelectedItems doesn't allow binding.

I've found several workarounds for this, such as using Behaviors to capture `SelectionChanged` and passing SelectedItems as a CommandParameter, or using the Style to bind the IsSelected property to the elements in my ItemsSource, but none of these appear to work. The behaviors never seem to pass anything but `null` and the IsSelected property never gets set.

The only thing that does appear to work is using the `SelectionChanged` event in the code-behind of my view. Even there I can't access the SelectedItems, nor the event's AddedItems / RemovedItems directly, as they appear to be unmanaged code, but I can loop over them and get the proper items. I suspect that this is where the issue lies; that for some reason the casting doesn't work, which is why my properties aren't set and my parameters are null.

I could technically use this to pass them on to my DataContext, but would prefer to avoid this as I would hope it should work the "regular" way.

Here's my (simplified) code with things that I have tried.

View:

```
    <views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="Console.UI.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:models="using:MyApp.Core.Models"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="using:MvvmCross.Platforms.Uap.Views"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.UI"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="MainViewPage"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:StateBrushConverter x:Key="StateBrushConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridViewDataTemplate" x:DataType="models:IListItem">
            <Grid Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateBrushConverter}}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Height="8"/>

                <SymbolIcon Visibility="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource StringVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,6" Symbol="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="6,0,6,6" FontSize="14em" Text="{Binding Text}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />

                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerReleased" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=grid}">                            
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickedCommand, ElementName=MainViewPage}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridViewControlTemplate" TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <GridViewItemPresenter Width="120" Height="90"
                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
                SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
                DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewDataTemplate}"
            />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <GridView Name="MyGrid" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectionChanged="MyGrid_OnSelectionChanged">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource GridViewControlTemplate}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <!--these are all the variations I have tried, but they all just produce null-->
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MyGrid}"/>
                        <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="SelectionChanged" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                        <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="SelectedListItems" TargetObject="{Binding}" Value="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MyGrid}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>        
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindowsPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void MyGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // here e.AddedItems, e.RemovedItems and sender.SelectedItems are all unmanaged System.__ComObject
            foreach (IListItem selectedItem in ((GridView)sender).SelectedItems)
            {
                // here I get the expected items
            }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public List<ListItem> MyList { get; }
        public List<ListItem> SelectedListItems { get; set; }

        public IMvxCommand<ListItem> ClickedCommand { get; }
        public IMvxCommand<object> SelectionChangedCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MyList = new List<ListItem>();
            SelectedListItems = new List<ListItem>();

            ClickedCommand = new MvxCommand<ListItem>(execute: Clicked);
            SelectionChangedCommand = new MvxCommand<object>(SelectionChanged);
        }

        private void SelectionChanged(object selectedItems)
        {
            // selectedItems is always null, even when I use IList<ListItem>
        }

        void Clicked(ListItem listItem)
        {
            
        }
    }

public abstract class ListItem : MvxViewModel, IListItem
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        private ListItemState _state;
        public ListItemState State
        {
            get => _state;
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(State));
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _isSelected;
            set
            {
                // never anything besides false
                _isSelected = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is, what am I missing, or what am I doing wrong to make this work?

Comment: Why are you defining a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `GridViewItem`? Do you have a downloadable and runnable sample somewhere?

Comment: @mm8 because there is another gridview on the page that needs to have the same style, this also allowed me to have a simple way to not show the checkboxes for multiselect (by not having those attributes)
I don't have a downloadable sample, as this is part of a proprietary project. Is there anything you're missing from the included code?

Comment: Simplify your code and try to reproduce this in a simple GridView without complex templates and styles.

Comment: @Anonymous, I have since tried disabling the ControlTemplate by disabling the Setter in ItemContainerStyle. This still produces the same result, the binding doesn't even fire, verified by using a Converter and never hitting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with the following code in your code-behind.

```
private void GridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView _gridview = sender as GridView;
        var items = _gridview.SelectedItems.ToList(); // this will create a new list
     
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //var item = p as youritemtype;


        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Here is an MVVM way to handle the selectionchanged event of the GridView

Xaml:

```
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Tool_Clicked}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyGridView}"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

Code-behind:

```
  public ICommand Tool_Clicked => new RelayCommand<Object>((s) =>
    {

        GridView _gridview = s as GridView;
        var source = _gridview.SelectedItems.ToList();


        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            //var item = p as youritemtype;


        }

    });
```

What I've done is to pass the GridView as a parameter when the command is fired. Then you could get the selected items from the GridView.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does in fact work, as I noted in my original post, and I've used this as a temporary workaround to build the list of selected items and pass them to my ViewModel. However, since I'm trying to use the MVVM pattern, I would really like to fix it with binding, and I can't figure out why it's not possible.
Just now I've tried to apply a converter to the ```IsSelected``` binding and it simply doesn't trigger at all. And passing the ```SelectedItems``` to a command, still does nothing either. So I get the feeling there is something really wrong with the binding itself

Comment: @Gamingdevil Could you please why do you want to bind the selected Items as parameters for that command. If you want to check the selected items, what about directly bind `SelectedListItems` property to the `GridView.SelectedItems` instead of passing parameters in the selected changed event?

Comment: Li, because when I apply a binding via ```SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedListItems}"```, I get a build error saying "Cannot assign 'Binding' into the read only property 'SelectedItems' "

Comment: @Gamingdevil That's interesting, I haven't find any code you posted that indicates the `SelectedListItems` is read-only. Is this property defined by your self?

Comment: Li, SelectedListItems is my own property, and is read/write. But The Gridview.SelectedItems is read-only, so it won't allow me to define binding.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I checked the document about `GirdVIew` and yes, the `Gridview.SelectedItems` is read-only. This could not be changed which means you can't bind to this property directly. So you still have to pass the `GridView` as the parameter. I've updated my answer and you could check it.

Comment: Roy, thanks again for your reply. Usually the Viewmodel project isn't supposed to know about the controls, so I don't have the needed reference to pass the Gridview.
Could you think of any reason why I can't pass the strongly typed SelectedItems as the parameter? Or why I can't simply bind to the IsSelected property between the ItemContainer and the ViewModels?
Both syntaxes are in my original post.

Comment: I haven't figure out why binding with element and path won't work yet. But still tracking this. You could submit an issue about this in [Xaml behavior Github](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors). Personally, I would not use Xaml Behavior to handle or binding events to ViewModel. I'll use Bind or x:Bind directly like SelectionChanged="{x:Bind Tool_Clicked}"